# Не могу ссылки вытащить

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Задача: На сайте собрать все ссылки в файлик. Но у меня собираются названия ссылок. 
Вопрос: Как в тэге -а- собрать только атрибуты href, то есть сами ссылки?

```
def get_books() -> typing.List[str]:
    rs = requests.get('https://site.ru')
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.text, 'html.parser')

    return [x.text.strip().replace('"', '') for x in root.findAll('a')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никто не читает [документацию](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)...

```
return [x.attrs['href'] for x in root.findAll('a') if 'href' in x.attrs]
```

Comment: Вот с таким логом валится, но спасибо за помощь)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/testby/Parsser.py", line 15, in <module>
    books = get_books()
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/testby/Parsser.py", line 11, in get_books
    return [x.attrs['href'] for x in root.findAll('a')]
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/testby/Parsser.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    return [x.attrs['href'] for x in root.findAll('a')]
KeyError: 'href'

Comment: @СергейБогданов значит у не которых ссылок нет атрибута `href`. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Через css можно указать наличие атрибута: `return [x.attrs['href'] for x in root.select('a[href]')]`

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос. Добавить надо:

`t = []
    for x in root.findAll('a'):
        try:
            t.append(x["href"].strip())
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return t`

И целиком:

```
def get_books() -> typing.List[str]:
rs = requests.get('https://site.ru')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.text, 'html.parser')

t = []
for x in root.findAll('a'):
    try:
        t.append(x["href"].strip())
    except KeyError:
        pass
return t
```

Может кому сгодится)